# Can the pre-image of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ under the function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, where the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$, be measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, definition, examples-counterexamples

This is a follow up to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706460/if-the-graph-of-a-measurable-function-is-dense-in-0-1-times0-1-can-the-pr). Note in the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706460/if-the-graph-of-a-measurable-function-is-dense-in-0-1-times0-1-can-the-pr), $f$ *can* have a range that’s a subset of $[0,1]$. Here, $f$ *must* have a range of $[0,1]$.

Suppose we define a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, such that using the Outer Lebesgue measure, the function is measurable in Caratheodory sense, and the range of the function is $[0,1]$.

**Main Question**

Can the pre-image of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ under $f$, where the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$, be measurable?

**Attempt:**

I'm not sure how to approach this question due to my lack of formal training beyond Intro to Advanced Math. I assume if the points in the graph of $f$ is "spread out enough" in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, there is some way to define $f$ where the pre-image of a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ under $f$ is measurable.

If this is not true, then the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707128/does-this-explicit-and-bijective-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motiva) doesn't give a function that satisfies the motivation of [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707128/does-this-explicit-and-bijective-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motiva).

In case you want to read the motivation here, read the following:

> I want to find a function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ whose graph is dense, and
> *somewhat*  but not *too evenly distributed* (i.e. with [complete spaical randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_spatial_randomness)), in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

If the *main question* is wrong is there some way to fix the main question of [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707128/does-this-explicit-and-bijective-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motiva) to satisfy my motivation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If the graph of a measurable function is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, can the pre-image of a non-measurable set be measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706460/if-the-graph-of-a-measurable-function-is-dense-in-0-1-times0-1-can-the-pr)

Comment: @AnotherUser As explained in the post, the range of $f$ *has* to be $[0,1]$. Note the answer to this post is different from the answer that you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f$: as shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662106), for any set $A \subset [0,1]$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

> The argument goes like this: $f^{-1}(A)$ is a union of at most countably many intervals (outside the Cantor set, where $f$ is locally constant), and a subset of the Cantor set (which has measure zero, and hence is measurable).

That's true in the particular case where $A$ is not measurable, which gives you an example.